# Is "the C# compiler" clever enough to remove code that has no side effect due to ConditionalAttribute optimization

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I understand that the Debug.WriteLine method has the ConditionalAttribute applied to them. This means that when a release build is done (or any build that doesn't define the DEBUG symbol) - this code will be excluded from the build.

This is perfect for what I want to do (show extra debug information when debugging my code - but have very optimized code in production). My system processes millions of records per minute and has no user interaction, so speed is king, even at a cost of other resources.

So, if I do a release build on code like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
   connection.InfoMessage += delegate (object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
   };
   return connection.Execute("procName", commandType: CMD.StoredProcedure);
}
```

I should end up with this:

```cs
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
   connection.InfoMessage += delegate (object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
   {
   };
   return connection.Execute("procName", commandType: CMD.StoredProcedure);
}
```

So, finally the question: Is "the compiler" generally clever enough to see that the below code does nothing and remove it too - or will it still generate an empty class + method and call it each time the code runs? (I believe that a delegate compiles to a "stub"-class containing the method - so there is some real overhead in this).

```cs
   connection.InfoMessage += delegate (object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
   {
   };
```

Would I still be better off (in terms of performance) doing something like this:

```cs
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
#if DEBUG 
   connection.InfoMessage += delegate (object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
   {
   };
#endif
   return connection.Execute("procName", commandType: CMD.StoredProcedure);
}
```

As fas as I can tell - it looks like the C# compiler should remove the single Debug.Writeline() call and the JIT compiler might then remove the empty method. Is this assumption accurate?

**Note:** Yes, I do understand that if I run this code millions of times in a loop, I'll be creating many, many, many connection objects and possibly db-connections - this is code to describe my question, not a snippet of my production code! :)

Comment: best way to answer this would be to compare the generated IL. but personally, i prefer to be explicit about what ends up in prod and what stays in debug, so `#if` is the way to go IMHO.

Comment: _I'll be creating many, many, many connection objects_ - creating connection instances is not an issue (same as creating other objects), but it will not create many many database connections, database connections will be provided by Connection pool, which will reuse already created connections.

Comment: @ Franz Gleichmann Thanks. I generally agree with being explicit and will probably end up going that way (unless someone here has a compelling argument in the other direction). My only objection to the #if-statements is that they tend to make the code look ugly :) :)

Comment: @Fabio. I can agree with your statement in broad - except that a) I don't believe that object creation comes at a trivial cost - object creation can be very expensive, b) I wanted the question to focus on the compiler issue and not the supporting code. In Retrospect, maybe I should have written this with a non-db example. c) Your observation is only correct when you make some sweeping assumptions about the contents of my connection string. I could just disable connection pooling in my connection string .

Comment: The second you do this `InfoMessage +=` its game over, nothing is going to optimizing this out completely. Anyway, prove it to your self with BenchmarkDotNet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we can see in [compilation results](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgdgpgLgZgHgGiiAlgGwD4AEBMBGAWACgsAGAAizwDoARAQynuoGUBHNAYTRQjCgDcxMpRq0U9AOZgA9gGcoKAMZyhRYQGZKOcp3IBvYuWOUtWACzkAsgAoAlAaMnnT58ZE2AbvQBO5JTJgkEqKgeQAvOSQAO7k7FyBwaFgNgBEUBAKqXZ2rm6GRG5F/okQISiB1ACSYDAyVplyUhDkANSRACYQaBCSjC02MsAAVmVQ5HJ8XT4IcRw1dQ1yTZIQAKKefFAAgj6ScuQQuYXFzgWnp7QQwACuktQA6j4oGQAyKJA2ENRLK0dqFxMAF8AcUgXkgSZiECgA===), the compiler will not eliminate event subscription. It will add event handler with empty body.

Moreover, as the event subscription itself can lead to the side effects (via the custom implementation of the event's `add` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/add) or with checks like `if(handler!=null){}` somewhere in the class), I do not think that such optimisation will be easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks @Serg. This makes total sense. I didn't even consider the side effects that the add method could potentially have....